# Android Webview: console is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to open a html with some javascripts in a Android Webview and getting the following error after implements onConsoleMessage of my WebChromeClient:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: console is not defined -- From line 10 of file:///storage/sdcard0/TargetApp/e184bae3-5824-4e23-a26e-820ce6d32aa2/pres/fce4da510de8431bB3eeD5bdbd1c695d/fce4da510de8431bB3eeD5bdbd1c695d/html/js/target/util_Q_3bb82a6eabd3339d91ca15cb4fd6685c.js
```

Follows the line 10 of my file:

```
console = console ? console : { log : function() {}, debug : function() {}};
```

The strange thing is that the same code works perfectly on browsers and IOS webview.

Is there somebody that could give me a hint about what is happening?

Comment: Have you tried this console = console || { log : function() {}, debug : function() {}};

Comment: Not yet, I'll try something different but the point of the question is why this simple conditional could be wrong.

Comment: Actually it works on every webview or browser that i've tested, unless android webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, unfortunally my code example was incomplete. The problem was that javascript was setting the Strict Mode

```
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    /* 
     * 
     */
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

    console = console ? console : { log : function() {}, debug : function() {}}; 

    window.c = console;

/*
* ...
*/
```

Specificacion says:

> With strict mode, you can not, for example, use undeclared variables.

So, the correct way is:

```
var console = window.console = window.console ? window.console : { log : function() {}, debug : function() {}};
```

The only question still open is why other browsers like Chrome, Firefox and ios it works